# Create stored procedure in Teradata from .net code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures, teradata

I try to create a stored procedure from .NET code using `Teradata.Client.Provider`.

I used a query like this:

```
"REPLACE PROCEDURE test_db.testproc() BEGIN END;"
```

All code:

```
...
    var connectionTd = new TdConnection("[ConnectionString]");
    var cmdTd = connectionTd.CreateCommand();
    cmdTd.CommandText = "REPLACE PROCEDURE test_db.testproc() BEGIN END;";
    connectionTd.Open();
    cmdTd.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

but I get an error:

> [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: Invalid  SQL Statement.

In IDE like dBeaver all works fine.

P.S.
Sample from [this](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider%7ETeradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand%7ECommandText.html) page causes the same error.

Comment: Which *method* are you invoking? The recommended approach is `cmd.ExecuteCreateProcedure`. Not sure why the example you linked references `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` instead.

Comment: @Fred this is a great clarification! if you format it as an answer I can mark it as correct! And show me where the documentation says about it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fred were able to find a solution!

It is enough to call instead of **ExecuteNonQuery()** -> **ExecuteCreateProcedure()**

```
...
    var connectionTd = new TdConnection("[ConnectionString]");
    var cmdTd = connectionTd.CreateCommand();
    cmdTd.CommandText = "REPLACE PROCEDURE test_db.testproc() BEGIN END;";
    connectionTd.Open();
    cmdTd.ExecuteCreateProcedure(true);
...
```

Comment: This is documented in the TdCommand Class help entry (the parent of the one you cited).